# Sending a text over socket after sending a file

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, socketexception

I have a client which will send a file to the server...the server gets the file in chunks and processes the data and send it back to the server. Later, after the file has bee transmitted fully, i want the server to tell the client whether the data was processed with or without any errors.

**Client : Using this code to send and receive file data**

```
    toServer = socket.getOutputStream();
    fromServer = socket.getInputStream();
    fileReader = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    fileWriter = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    while ((count = fileReader.read(bytes)) > 0) {
        toServer.write(bytes, 0, count);
        total_received = 0;
        while(total_received < count) {
            incount = fromServer.read(inbytes);
            total_received += incount;
            fileWriter.write(inbytes, 0, incount);
        }
    }
    toServer.close(); //to break the while loop on server
    incount = fromServer.read(inbytes);
    System.out.println(incount);
```

**Server :**

```
    while ((count = fromClient.read(bytes)) > 0) 
    {
       //processedBytes
        toClient.write(processedBytes, 0, count);
    }
    toClient.write("Process done!".getBytes(), 0, "Process done!".length());
    toClient.flush();
```

**Problem :**

The file is being transferred successfully.....but the message after processing the file is not being received by the client....i get **java.net.SocketException: Socket closed** on the client side. I understand that the socket gets closed on the server side while the client is still listening bringing up the SocketException. But what happens to the **toClient.write()** statement in the server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried putting inner while loop out?

Comment: On the client side, yes. But the server closes the socket anyways and the same exception is thrown.

Comment: print and check the length of `processedBytes` in server side and `count` in client side. ideally it should be same, if my understanding is correct.

Comment: processedBytes and count are connected to the file transfer and they are working fine.....i just want to send a message from server to client after both of them have exited from their while loops!

Comment: try `toServer.flush();` instead of `toServer.close();` in client.

Comment: toServer.flush() works but toServer.close() is to make the server exit its while loop......is there any other way to break the server's while loop?!

Comment: but yes the problem is with toServer.close(). Just have to find another way to break the while loop on the server when the file is over.

Comment: BufferedReader could be a solution. believe this would help. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html.

Comment: BufferedReader cannot be a solution bro....cannot add a new line character at the end of file data chunks right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call `toServer.close()` as it closes the socket as well. If you want to break the while loop on server you need to send some special character like SOH character which could be searched on server side and as soon as server gets that it terminates the loop and sends the ack back to client and then client can close the socket.

Comment: I did it and it worked.....but why does a socket close when i close the output stream?

Comment: Refer to javadocs of `getOutputStream()` and `getInputStream()` from socket class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html and i think this is implemented like this because socket is supposed to be 2 way communicator so if you close one route (output) there is no way of knowing if the other route (input) is still alive and useful.