# Sending a string after a file on the same socket

Tags: java, string, sockets

I'm sending a string over the socket I previously sent a file to, but the recipient reads it as part of the file itself, is there a way to send a sort of EOF before sending the string?

To send the file I'm using

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int count;
while ((count = fis.read(buffer)) >= 0) os.write(buffer, 0, count);
os.flush();
```

(and almost the same to receive it)

To send the string I'm using OutputStreamWriter

(Here you are my code: [hatebin](https://hatebin.com/kahrqkmqas))

I've also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29234321/14059176) that I should send a SOH character, but which one should I send and how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there's no way to send an "eof" and then send something afterwards.

If you don't want to open a new connection, there are basically two ways to solve this.

- You can modify the client so it recognizes some special byte sequence as a "delimiter", and stops writing to the file when it reads the delimiter from the socket. In this case you need to have some strategy to deal with the possibility that the file actually contains the delimiter.
- You can send the size of the file in bytes before sending the file, and modify the client so it counts the number of bytes it reads from the socket. When the client has read enough, it should stop writing to the file.